# How to import datatypes in .proto files in GRPC in java/android?

Tags: java, android, grpc, proto, grpc-java

I am trying to make an app using GRPC protocols. In my .proto file I need to import timestamp class and as per google documentation, 
`import google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` 
is how we should add to proto file. But its giving me error

> import google/protobuf/timestamp.proto is not found or has
>   errors

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting a [known issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1889); neither the well-known protos nor their generated code are included in protobuf-lite.

A workaround is to add an extra dependency and generate the code yourself. Assuming you are using Gradle and already using the `com.google.protobuf` plugin, you just need to add a [`protobuf` dependency](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#protos-in-dependencies) for the `.proto` files (or a JAR including the `.proto` files) you have a dependency on:

```
dependencies {
  protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.2'
}
```